# (CLASS*)int to shared_ptr<CLASS>(int) not work

Tags: c++, c++17, smart-pointers

I want to convert the source to a smart pointer.
But I found one I don’t understand why it can’t.
How can this be solved with the code below?

Old code style:

```
bool PyTuple_GetTextInstance(PyObject* poArgs, int pos, CGraphicTextInstance** ppTextInstance)
{
    int handle;
    if (!PyTuple_GetInteger(poArgs, pos, &handle))
        return false;

    if (!handle)
        return false;

    *ppTextInstance=(CGraphicTextInstance*)handle;

    return true;
}
```

new code style:

```
bool PyTuple_GetTextInstance(PyObject* poArgs, int pos, std::shared_ptr<CGraphicTextInstance>& ppTextInstance)
{
    int handle;
    if (!PyTuple_GetInteger(poArgs, pos, &handle))
        return false;

    if (!handle)
        return false;

    ppTextInstance=std::static_pointer_cast<CGraphicTextInstance>(handle);

    return true;
}
```

why not work? problem: std::static_pointer_cast error

invitation:

```
PyObject* grpTextGetSize(PyObject* poSelf, PyObject* poArgs)
{
    CGraphicTextInstance* pTextInstance;
    if (!PyTuple_GetTextInstance(poArgs, 0, &pTextInstance))
        return Py_BuildException();

    int width, height;
    pTextInstance->GetTextSize(&width, &height);
    return Py_BuildValue("(i, i)", width, height);
}
```

PyTuple_GetInteger function:

```
bool PyTuple_GetInteger(PyObject* poArgs, int pos, int* ret)
{
    if (pos >= PyTuple_Size(poArgs))
        return false;

    PyObject* poItem = PyTuple_GetItem(poArgs, pos);

    if (!poItem)
        return false;

    *ret = PyLong_AsLong(poItem);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Whatever `handle` is/means, it's *not* a smart pointer. So it's not clear how exactly you expect to be able to convert it to one. Who owns it? How is the shared_ptr expected to delete it? Your code doesn't make sense.

Comment: That's right, that's why I was weird. I updated the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the original code is correct and that `handle` is really a pointer to a `CGraphicTextInstance` under the skin, then you need to replace this:

```
ppTextInstance=std::static_pointer_cast<CGraphicTextInstance>(handle);
```

with this:

```
ppTextInstance = std::shared_ptr <CGraphicTextInstance>
    (reinterpret_cast <CGraphicTextInstance *> (handle));
```

But it would be cleaner for this function to return a `shared_ptr <CGraphicTextInstance>`, with the wrapped pointer set to `nullptr` on failure.

Comment: I understand now. thank you very much. you're right.

Comment: I forgot to add: casting an `int` to a pointer will only work in 32 bit builds.